# How & Why to use SUPER in code?

Tags: javascript, keyword, superclass, super

I work with some advanced JavaScript people and they have used the SUPER keyword in their code. I admit, I don't have a good grasp of how and why one can and would use this.

Can someone direct me or show me how to become well versed in its usage and reasoning thereof?

Here are some examples:

```
openup: function( $super ) {
    $super();
    this.shop.enable_access();
}



addLeft: function( data ) {
    var cell = Element('td');
    if ( data.item_data ) {
        var item = new SRIL(data.item_data);
        item.attach(cell);
        item.show();
    }

    return cell;
```

}

```
var SRIL = Class.create(Module, {
initialize: function( $super, data ) {
    $super({ dom: 'show_line' });
    this.data = data;
    if ( data.Type[0] == 'Car' ) {
        //some code
    }
    else {
        // some code
    }
}
```

});

Comment: do you mean `SUPER` or `super`? case matters.

Comment: `$super` changes things - it isn't a keyword but just a variable.

Comment: It looks to me like this code is built on the Prototype.js framework: http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have such a thing.

Update: You should have a look at the documentation of the library that is in use here. This is a library feature, not a language one.

Comment: It is a [reserved future keyword](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1.2), so it does "have" it. I don't know if there is any implementation that uses it, though.

Comment: Is it not possible to create classes in JS and inherit them as a SUPER class? Think I saw something like that in coffeescript.

Comment: @Alex M: It is possible, but only if you implement it yourself with prototypes, not with JavaScript itself. This questions seems like a Java <-> JavaScript issue to me.

Comment: @copy: Do you mean prototype inheritance with "prototypes"? Why do you say it is not JavaScript? Prototype inheritance is how JavaScript manages the inheritance of objects.

Comment: @FelixKling: I was saying that JavaScript *itself* does not have a feature to reuse constructors (like Java's `super`). And it is not possible to create this with the keyword `super` since it's reserved. So I guessed this was mistake by the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

Since Javascript doesn't have classical inheritance, structured instead according to a prototypal/functional model, developers have made various attempts at re-creating the classical model. `super` is part of one such strategy. The particular problem it solves is in the case of a child object that has the same method – even if it's just the constructor – as the parent object. Without creating `super` as an alias to the parent's methods, accessing such methods becomes somewhat cumbersome (and, in some cases, impossible).

John Resig has a [wrapper](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) that shows this off fairly well. Note his use of _super() in the first example to call the parent object's dance method.

Comment: I added some examples of what I am seeing in the code for your reference on its usage.

Comment: In those cases, the devs are probably using `$super` to refer to parent methods directly. In other words I assume `$super` refers to a parent method called `open_up` in the first example, and to a parent `initialize` method in the second.