# Does super() map to __proto__ under the hood?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I understand that classes in ES6 are really syntactic sugar.  Is the super() call really just calling **proto**?  (Is it mapped to the [[prototype]] object?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765242/how-why-to-use-super-in-code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034059/javascript-whats-the-difference-between-call-and-super

Comment: [Google search: what is super keyword in js](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+super+keyword+in+js+site:stackoverflow.com&client=firefox-b-ab&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFyf723rfaAhUBmJAKHbwoAcgQrQIITygEMAI&biw=1366&bih=664)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: No, it is not calling `__proto__`. That's a deprecated getter/setter and should not be used by anything.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit more than that. It also remembers where the method was defined.

```
const example = {
    method() {
        return super.method();
    }
}
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
const example = {
    method() {
        return Object.getPrototypeOf(example).method.call(this);
    }
}
```

and

```
class Example {
    method() {
        return super.method();
    }
}
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
class Example {
    method() {
        return Object.getPrototypeOf(Example.prototype).method.call(this);
    }
}
```

As for `super()` calls in constructors, it similarly uses `Object.getPrototypeOf` on the constructor, but [does a bit more there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458960/1048572).

> Is it mapped to the [[prototype]] object?

Yes. Not to the [[prototype]] of the object that the function was called on (`this`), but to the [[prototype]] of the object that the function was defined in.