# Access parent (super) method in object created by Object.create

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, ecmascript-6, super

I want to create a wrapper mechanism: we wrap `c` so new new object `w` has own properties and methods but `c`'s are also accessible.

```
// Note: this class might be from an external lib
class C {
  f() {
    console.log('f (original)');
    this.p = 'p';
  }
}

class W {
  f() {
    console.log('f (new)');
    super.f();  // TypeError: (intermediate value).f is not a function
    console.log(this.p);
  }
}

// Note: this value is external for us
const c = new C();

const w = Object.create(null, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(W.prototype));
Object.setPrototypeOf(w, c);

w.f();  // expected:
        // f (new)
        // f (original)
        // p
```

Do I do this in correct manner?

Why is error happen?

**Update**: P.S. I do understand that I could use composition but I want to understand the source of error.

Comment: possible a duplicate of, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107556/how-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-javascript ... read it there, it might solve your problem.

Comment: @gugateider thanks but sorry, i don't see an answer there

Comment: What `obj` do you want to wrap? There is no `obj` variable in the code you posted.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49822270/1048572) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27511897/1048572)

Comment: Update: P.S. I do understand that I could use composition but I want to understand the source of error.

Comment: @Bergi, `c`. Thanks for links. But why is error happen? I don't see there...

Comment: @JakeHolzinger 'The `super` keyword requires the `extends` keyword' - from ECMAScript standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the error happen?

Because the `W.prototype.f` method that uses `super` only cares about the prototype of `W.prototype` to evaluate what `super` will refer to. The `super` keyword is essentially a static lookup, depending on the object in which the method was declared, ignoring the prototype chain of the object that the method was called on.

If we [translate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49822056/1048572) to

```
class W {
  f() {
    console.log('f (new)');
    Object.getPrototypeOf(W.prototype).f.call(this); // TypeError: (intermediate value).f is not a function
    console.log(this.p);
  }
}
```

we can see that `Object.prototype.f` is not a function…

---

So you could fix the issue by doing `Object.setPrototypeOf(W.prototype, C.prototype)` instead of `Object.setPrototypeOf(w, c)` (or `w = Object.create(c, …)`), but I can't recommend that. If you really wanted to affect all instances, you'd have written `class W extends C` already (which would have the same result as using `Object.setPrototypeOf(W.prototype, C.prototype)`).

Comment: Ahhh, I forget that `f` is not  `W.f` but `W.prototype.f`... Now I see al the chain! Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the `extends` keyword for example:

```
    class C {
        f() { console.log( "C.f" ); }
    }

    class W extends C {
        f() {
            super.f()
            console.log( "W.f" );
        }
    }

    const w = new W();
    w.f(); // will output C.f W.f
```

Comment: No. Object `c` is given by call of external llibrary's function. It's properties are not accessible in your code.

We can use composition. But that's another story...