# Why I can't use 'super' in prototype method definition when I can use Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype)?

Tags: javascript, es6-class, prototypal-inheritance, javascript-inheritance

So I tested this code:

```
class C1 {}

C1.prototype. f =function(){ return 1 }

class C2 extends C1 {}

C2.prototype. f =function(){ return super.f()+1 }
```

And it throws a syntax error: 'super' keyword unexpected here.

But if I do:

```
C2.prototype. f =function(){ return Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype).f() + 1 }
```

It does return a two!

So does anyone know why 'super' doesn't work? I see no reason for it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can only use `super` expressions in method in a `class` declaration or in an object initializer expression. You're trying to use it in a plain function.

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype)` isn’t how `super` works, either – it’s more like `C2.prototype`, which should hopefully make it clearer why it can’t work in an arbitrary function expression.

Comment: @Ry-. why doesn't it work so? Why can't 'super' be `Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype)`? Looks like what I proposed works exactly as intended and is even superior to how 'super' works now. I just don't understand what's the advantage in the way it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @user1533299: Imagine if you had `class C3 extends C2 {}` and tried to call `new C3().f()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822056/does-super-map-to-proto-under-the-hood/49822270#49822270

Comment: @Ry-, it returned 3. What's wrong with that? Didn't it work as intended?

Comment: @user1533299: Oh yes, sorry, the other bug in the implementation affects this: you need to `.f.call(this)` instead of just `.f()`, or you won’t be able to access any instance properties (plus overriding methods won’t work properly).

Comment: @Bergi, that answer says it's just syntatic sugar but if that was so it'd work outside of class{} block, no?

Comment: @Ry-, true, good point! But I believe my question still stands: WHY isn't `super` just synthatic sugar for `Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype)[method].call(this)` ?

Comment: @user1533299: Once that bug is fixed, return to my previous example.

Comment: @Ry-, oh... I see! Thanks. This feels like correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: @user1533299 "*if that was so it'd work outside of class{} block, no?*" - no. Notice the desugared code has a static reference to the prototype object (in case of `class`). That doesn't work in a normal `function`, there is no such owning object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype).f()` loses the instance:

```js
class C1 {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    f() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}

class C2 extends C1 {
    f() {
        Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype).f();
    }
}

new C1(42).f();  // 42
new C2(42).f();  // undefined
```

(because `this === C1.prototype` when a function is called as `C1.prototype.f()`)

`Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype).f.call(this)` always has `this.constructor` as the bottom of the class hierarchy, which breaks when you add a level:

```js
class C1 {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    f() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}

class C2 extends C1 {
    f() {
        Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype).f.call(this);
    }
}

class C3 extends C2 {}

new C1(42).f();  // 42
new C2(42).f();  // 42
new C3(42).f();  // infinite recursion
```

A correct version for reasonable code would be

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(/* containing class */.prototype).f.call(this)
```

[which is basically what `super` does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822056/does-super-map-to-proto-under-the-hood/49822270#49822270) – and for that, it needs to know the containing class (or object), which doesn’t necessarily exist for arbitrary function expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`super` is a `keyword` meaning it must be accepted by the interpreter and currently only `class` can use it. You must backup your method or refer to it remotely if you want the same effect:

```js
class C1 {}

C1.prototype. f =function(){ return 1 }

class C2 extends C1 {}

C2.prototype. f =function(){ return C1.prototype.f.call(this)+1 }
```

Comment: also when using `getPrototypeOf` it works just a coincidence that is not how `super` works

Comment: coincidence? Why doesn't `super` work that way, though? Wouldn't it be more powerful if it did?

Comment: because it's too easy to hack